# regex not removing underscore from pattern

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to code for allowing certain special characters in a string by using java.util.regex.Matcher and java.util.regex.pattern but this is not removing underscore from the same. I'm new here. I need help on this.
Code extract below:

```
  // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
  String line = "This order was _:$ placed for QT3000! OK?";
  String pattern = "[^\\w\\s\\-?:().,'+\\/]";
  String s = null;

  // Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  s= m.replaceAll("");
  System.out.println("Output: " + s);
```

Expected: This order was : placed for QT3000 OK?
Actual  : This order was _: placed for QT3000 OK?

Comment: I think underscore is a *word* character, so `\\w` includes it.

Comment: `\w` matches underscores. Replace with `\p{Alnum}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\w` pattern matches underscores and `[^\w]` matches any char but letters, digits and an underscore.

Replace with `\p{Alnum}`:

```
String pattern = "[^\\p{Alnum}\\s?:().,'+/-]";
```

Note I put the hyphen at the end of the character class so as not to escape it and remove the escaping `\` from the `/` as it is not a special regex metacharacter.

See the [Java regex demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyu0f0uyr).

The `[^\\p{Alnum}\\s?:().,'+/-]` pattern matches any char but:

- `\p{Alnum}` - alphanumeric `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
- `\s` - whitespaces
- `?` - a question mark
- `:` - a colon
- `(` - a `(` symbol
- `)` -  a `)` symbol
- `.` - a dot
- `,` - a comma
- `'`  - a single quotation mark
- `+`  - a plus
- `/` - a forward slash
- `-` - a hyphen.

Comment: `\p{Alnum}` stands for `[A-Za-z0-9]` if `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` option is not set. If it is, then it matches all Unicode letters and digits.